# Dynamic Script in IFrame not triggering window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onload-event

I am dynamically creating an `IFrame` then adding a `script` tag to it with code that should execute when the frame loads, however it is never executed.

```
$stage.html("<iframe src='javascript:;' id='frame'></iframe>");
$frame = $("#frame");

frame =  $frame[0].contentDocument ? $frame[0].contentDocument :  $frame[0].contentWindow.document;

script= frame.createElement('script'),
head = frame.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

script.innerHTML = "window.onload = function() { alert('loaded'); }";

head.appendChild(script);
```

I am assuming the `window onload` event is triggered before the code is added to the `IFrame`. Is there anyway to ensure it is called? Also it needs to be contained with in `window.onload` as it is for a JS based code editor so the iframe has to react as it would in a browser window. Cheers.

Comment: I think the window is already loaded so you're code missed the onload event. If it's not already loaded then the getElementsByTagName will fail. I'm not sure about this though so I didn't make it a formal answer

Comment: Good point. Is there another way I can inject code into an iframe and have it execute on `window.onload`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using `window.write()`.

```
frame = document.createElement("iframe"); 
frame.src = "javascript:;";
document.body.appendChild(frame);

win = frame.contentWindow;
win.document.open();
win.document.write(html);
win.document.close();
```