# Race condition with addEventListener. When to bind?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I am using post message to adjust the height of an iframe dynamically. The html that is holding the iframe adds a listener that will trigger the frame resize. The (simplified) relevant code on the parent looks something like this:

```
<div id="dynamic_content">
    <iframe  src="http://my.content"></iframe>-->
</div>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        window.addEventListener("message", handleEventTrigger, false);
    };

    function handleEventTrigger(evt) {
        var height = evt.data;
        alert("Received: " + evt.data);
        if (isNumber(height)) {
            $("#dynamic_content").height(height + "px");
        }
    }

    function isNumber(str) {
        return !isNaN(str - 0);
    }    
</script>
```

On the source for the iframe I trigger a postMessage when it loads. Basically I have a div with id outerDiv which I want to send the height of. The relevant javascript code is:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var height = $("#outerDiv")[0].offsetHeight;
    if (isNumber(height)) {
        parent.postMessage(height, "*");   
    }        
};
```

My problem now is that this only works occasionally. I am assuming there is a race condition between adding the event listener and firing the post message. I rely on having bound the event listener before the post message is fired. What is the appropriate way to ensure this? Both are bound to `window.onload`. Are these addressing the same `window`, and is this a/the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743519/dynamic-script-in-iframe-not-triggering-window-onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand the code is executed in the order it is printed, so I solved this by making sure the `addEventListener` is placed before the `<iframe>` in the code - and also stop doing this onload:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("message", handleEventTrigger, false);        
    function handleEventTrigger(evt) { ... }
</script>

<iframe  src="http://my.content"></iframe>-->
```

This solves the problem, and my race condition is gone. However, from what I've understood the recommendation is to place the js-code at the end of the html. If there is a good solution where I can achieve this too please shout out..

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess but a race condition or asynchronous timeing can be avoid when you not post the height but a callback function name so that the listener must call that function to get the current height of the iframe.

Comment: I can't see how this changes anything? Then I would have the same race condition on getting the function name to call. I could trigger a postMessage from the parent to the iframe when everything is loaded to tell the iframe to post its height, but I'd rather have this work simply by reporting (without requesting).

Comment: You say "not post the height, but a callback function name". From what I understand you're saying the iframe content should post the name of a function instead of the height. Right? The problem is that the parent doesn't get the height due to the race condition. I will have the same problem even if it posts a callback function name. I need to have the postMessage happen later - or have the addEventListener happen earlier. I don't see how this solves that particular problem.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. I thought about the race condition about a code that only differ in 1 bit. For example in a karnaugh-map you can identify race conditions when you have to design a logical circuit. Maybe it's just a language thing.